# Azure AD Graph group member oData result limitations

Tags: select, odata, azure-ad-graph-api

Following is the url to get the members of a group

baseUrl/groups/{groupId}/members?**$select**=objectId,signInNames,surname,givenName

**So how many number of records will be return with this request**?
does it return all the members of group or does it return limited number of record and next link for the next records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how many members are in your group.

Different APIs might have different default and maximum page sizes.

There should be a limited number(which is not exposed) for `/members` endpoint. If the number of members exceeds this limit, a `@odata.nextLink` will be returned for accessing more data.

You can specify the page size by using `$top` query parameter. See details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging).

Comment: Thank you. I agree with you . But actually i need to know what is the maximum number of result will return from Azure ad graph for the enpoint baseUrl/groups/{groupId}/members?$select=objectId,signInNames,surname,givenName

Comment: @smith Based on my test in Microsoft Graph explorer, the default maximum number of `/members` is 100. And a helpful issue here for your reference: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/4636#issuecomment-500247871. The answerer also says **in Azure AD (users, groups, devices etc) the default is 100**.

Comment: @smith Do you have any other concerns? If it's helpful, you can accept it as answer. Thank you!